# A follow up to "Tensorflow: How to extract attention_scores for graphing?"

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to understand how multihead attention works and how you can visualize the weights and I stumbled on this StackOverflow question [Tensorflow: How to extract attention_scores for graphing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70573362/tensorflow-how-to-extract-attention-scores-for-graphing). What I do not understand is, given that the input of my model is (batch_size, number_time_steps, number_features), and the output is a prediction of shape (batch_size, number_time_steps, 1), what is the "source" and "target" that I see in many of the codes? For example: `model.fit([train_targets, train_sources], y, batch_size=2, epochs=2)`.

**y** in this case is the prediction you know, but the training data is source and target and I don't know what it means and why it has different shapes.

Comment: You might want to look at self attention for your use case. See also: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/MultiHeadAttention.

Comment: This questions are for using multihead as self attention. For what I understood, the target and source are what you are trying to focus the attention between, so if target and source are the input data for the train step, it becames self attention cause the layer will try to find relationships between itself, right?

Comment: Yes exactly, for a text generation task, it allows the model to weigh the importance of different tokens within a context window when predicting the next token. These tokens make up one single input / sentence.

Comment: This question is a follow up [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76541808/visualizing-multiheadattention-activation) I made to help me understand what's happening to be able able to visualize correctly the output weight. I want to display a heatmap of the attention over the data to see where the attention is